# Python Sqlanydb cannot connect to Sybase due to password encryption required

Tags: python, database, sybase

I am trying to connect to a Sybase database that requires password encryption. I am using the sqlanydb library with python. I am able to connect to other Sybase databases that do not require password encryption. Any assist would be much appreciated. (see code below).

import sqlanydb

conn = sqlanydb.connect(uid='user', pwd='password',host ='server:port',dbn='dbname')

curs = conn.cursor()

**Error Output:**
OperationalError: Connection error: Connection was dropped (may not be a SQL Anywhere server)

Comment: Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried the ocs.cfg fix listed here if not it could be worth a shot as i dont see anything in the python module about setting extra connection string options?
https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Management/Configure-connection-to-Sybase-where-password-encryption-is/td-p/233701